# How did the first loop begin in Triangle?

Tags: plot-explanation, time-travel, triangle

How did the first loop begin in Triangle? One Jess is killed in the car crash. Why doesn't she move forward to the loop?

Comment: I think you may find the answer you are looking for here: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/509/is-the-time-loop-on-the-cruise-ship-a-second-timeline-in-triangle

Comment: Can you be more specific? Yes she dies at car crash, then she's on cruise...

Comment: If the movie shows Jess's afterlife, then there doesn't necessarily have to be *any* beginning. The afterlife experience is simply a never-ending sequence; it *always* has three generations of Jess on board the ship.