# How come the ship in Triangle is empty?

Tags: plot-explanation, triangle

[This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/509/is-the-time-loop-on-the-cruise-ship-a-second-timeline-in-triangle) (and its corresponding answers) do a good job of explaining how the time loop influences the story, but there's one thing I still don't understand - how did the ship in the middle of the ocean get there in the first place, and how come it's deserted? And how come it stops for the crew to climb aboard?

We don't see Jess at the controls to stop the ship at all, and we never see any hint of any other crew (though we do see plenty of evidence that her time loop has occurred many times before on that very ship of course.)

Is there some symbolism that it's just driving itself that I've missed, or something else entirely?

Comment: the ship is the vessel of her punishment

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed a very critical part of the story.

Reff: [Triangle Movie Explained](https://www.thisisbarry.com/film/triangle-2009-movie-plot-ending-explained/)

Jess is dead when she reaches the liner in the middle of the ocean. This part of the movie is all about the punishment she is receiving because she breaks her promise with death (the taxi driver).

She's made to go through a never ending loop of pain till she accepts her death and the responsibility of the death of her autistic son.

She is, however, shown to not accept it even in the end and the loop starts all over again.

Comment: Nope, I understand that Jess is dead - but everything else in the film that happens after this point can be explained in lieu of this (in the context of the time loop.) The radio call for help, the multiple sets of people on the ship, the rather horrifying array of dead Sally's, the multiple buried birds, etc. - but the presence of this huge ship that's entirely unpopulated aside from the time loop and magically stops for the party to climb aboard is not something that I've managed to figure out. Of course, there may not be a definite answer - but doesn't hurt to ask :)

Comment: Given events are not in the real world, the huge ship is not real either. Everything is part of the metaphorical punishment that Jess is being subjected to. Therefore the ship can quite drive itself because the real world laws don't apply.

Comment: @berry120 isn't the ship magically there because all the scenes in the movie on the ship blah blah are part of Jessie's after death?